# Problema al hacer scraping con Python a una página dinámica PHP

Tags: php, python, scraping, python-requests, beautifulsoup

Al hacer un *request.get* a una *pagina.php* para consumir una tabla y luego extraerla con  **BeautifulSoup** ésta llega sin contenido.

Estoy utilizando las siguientes librerias: **urlopen**, **requests**, **BeautifulSoup**.

¿Cómo podría hacer el *scraping* a una pagina .php que contiene una tabla utilizando Python?

Este es mi código:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = urlopen(
    'https://www.sicoes.gob.bo/portal/contrataciones/busqueda/convocatorias.php')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

tabla = soup.find('table')
print(tabla)
```

Comment: Por lo que he visto la página es interceptada  por una ventana emergente que impide llegar a ella. Sin embargo, utilizando una conexión previa al portal y luego la conexión a la página puedes lograr acceder a la página, sin embargo, los datos de la tabla se procesan luego de cargar la pagina y en consecuencia solo se obtiene la fila de cabecera. Creo que deberías utilizar algo como Selenium para hacer el scraping.

Comment: Otra opción que dispones es mirar el archivo JS, encontrar la dirección del fichero donde se obtienen los datos para rellenar la tabla (entiendo que seré un PHP) y hacer el request sobre ese fichero. Podría ser la dirección /portal/comunicados/operacion.php, con un GET donde le pasa un parámetro.

Comment: Agrégale al url el parámetro ?tipo=convNacional.. pero igual no podrás recuperar la tabla (solo el header) porque los resultados se muestran luego de unos segundo o menos luego de cargar la página. Por otro lado la tabla tiene paginación y por cada cambio de página los datos se traen del servidor por lo que no podrás cargar toda la tabla. Tampoco veo que tenga alguna opción de descarga. Te recomendaría que veas el Selenium.